# load environment variables from a file in a makefile on windows

Tags: windows, makefile, environment-variables

So I wanted to create a `make run` command so that I can test locally. It loads some env vars before running it.

I have a `win.env` file

```
set ENV1=val1
set ENV2=val2
```

and a `lin.env` file

```
export ENV1=val1
export ENV2=val2
```

in the `Makefile` I have:

```
run:
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    . ./win.env && go run .
else
    . ./lin.env && go run .
endif
```

On linux it works, but on windows it says:

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable probram or batch file.
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

How can I load the env vars before running my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` command is a feature of the POSIX shell.  You are not using a POSIX shell on Windows, you're using Windows cmd.exe.

First, you can't name the file `win.env`.  Windows cares a lot about file extensions so you'll have to name this file `win.bat` or something like that.

Second, in Windows cmd.exe you just run the script; it doesn't start a new command program like POSIX systems do.

```
run:
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
        win.bat; go run .
else
        . ./lin.env && go run .
endif
```